# How to determine a shape of input and output nodes in graph. (Tensorflow C++)

Tags: tensorflow

At first, I tried to implement the following pipeline:

- 1a) I converted the model from keras (.hdf5) to tensorflow (.pb) and saved using the `tf.saved_model.simple_save` function in Python.
- 2a) I loaded the model using `tensorflow::LoadSavedModel`
- 3a) I determined a shape using the following code:

```
const string export_dir = "/home/user/MyBuild/build_tftest2/models";
 SavedModelBundle bundle; RunOptions run_options;
status = LoadSavedModel(sopt, run_options, export_dir,
               {kSavedModelTagServe}, &bundle);
if (status.ok())
{
    GraphDef graph = bundle.meta_graph_def.graph_def();
    auto shape = graph.node().Get(0).attr().at("shape").shape();
    for (int i = 0; i < shape.dim_size(); i++) {
        std::cout << shape.dim(i).size()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Later I was wishing to use optimal model, therefore I used another pipeline:

- 1b) I converted the model from keras (.hdf5) to tensorflow (.pb) using

```py
frozen_graph = convert_variables_to_constants(session, input_graph_def,
output_names, freeze_var_names)
```

and saved in Python using:

```py
tf.train.write_graph(frozen_graph, "model", "tf_model.pb", as_text=False)
```

- 2b) I optimized the model using the `transform_graph` utility from tensorflow package.
- 3b) I loaded my graph using the following code (C++):

```
status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), "/home/user/MySoftware/foreign code/netology_JN/Diplom/Models/optimized/optim_model.pb", &graph_def);
```

- 4b) I tried to determine a shape using 3a) and an exception was thrown:

```
[libprotobuf FATAL /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map.h:1064]
CHECK failed: it != end(): key not found: shape terminate called after
throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException' what():
CHECK failed: it != end(): key not found: shape 14:21:36: The program
has unexpectedly finished.
```